# FancyBox iframe height issue

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, fancybox-2

I'm using FancyBox iframes to display some responsive Bootstrap content. This works great on large screens, scaling the height to exactly fit the content. However, **the same height** is used on smaller devices even though the responsive content has become taller and there is plenty of room on the screen for the iframe to be taller? It looks like FancyBox is finding the height of the full width version of the content even though a narrower/taller version is being displayed?

See these screenshots:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lfr5onr3ilmpkk/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-16%20at%2018.31.57.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6t4jn1abtrqr17h/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-16%20at%2018.32.11.png?dl=0

Does anybody have any advice on a solution?

Here's my code:

```
$(".fancyiframe").fancybox( {
    maxWidth: '100%',
    height: 'auto',
    fitToView: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    type: 'iframe'
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with classes to help with responsive embedding that might help you.

```
 <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Comment: Thanks Christopher but the content isn't video and has no intrinsic ratio. I think the issue is with FancyBox?